# AppBar Material UI questions

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I'm pretty new to the Material UI Library but I really like it so far! However, i am having an issue with the AppBar component overlaying over my other content. I currently have `<AppBar />` and `<myComponent />` in my App.js render method. Here is the code snippet for that:

```
render(){
   return (
   <div>
      <AppBar />
      <myComponent />
   </div>
   );
}
```

This is the code for the myComponent function:

```
function myComponent(){
   return (
   <h1>
      Hello
   </h1>
   );
}
```

However, when I run this code, the "Hello" message is overlaid by the AppBar component. Is there some way to have my hello message (and corresponding code) be displayed under the AppBar? It's a simple question but I would love to figure this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `paddingTop` to the containing `div` to compensate for the height of the `AppBar` (64px by default):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ paddingTop: 64 }}>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
            Title
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <YourComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This definitely works but is there a better way to handle this situation? Surely Material UI has to be able to arrange the components in such a way that this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the top margin from top to the component which you have created   right below the app bar

I am posting this from mobile if you need code just let me know I will right it for you

Comment: Yes @shubham you are right , hey man do the same it work as same

Comment: Hey @shubham, could you give me that code snippet when you have a moment? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `position: "sticky"` prop for appbar did the trick for me:

```
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar sx={{position: "sticky"}}/>
      <myComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```