# AppBar overlaps with other elements

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I am starting to use React/Material-UI, and also new to CSS etc...
I have a simple page layout with an APPBar. Unfortunately this AppBar overlaps the elements which are meant to go below it.

I have found this answer:
[AppBar Material UI questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992733/appbar-material-ui-questions)

But this feels completely wrong. What if my AppBar has a variable height, depending on the icons, display modes etc...?

I have tried to create a vertical grid, to wrap the elements in different items, made the top container a flex one and play with flex settings, nothing seems to work, the app bar always sits on top of the text.

The code is very simple:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Typography, Box } from '@material-ui/core';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar>
                <Typography variant='h3'>
                    AppBar
                </Typography>
            </AppBar>
            <Box>
                <Typography variant='h1' style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
                    Hello
                </Typography>
            </Box>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

The "Hello" text chunk is only half visible:

[image]

Comment: Now I have the same problem with you hahaha have you found the answer?

Comment: Yes, you can set the AppBar position to relative: `<AppBar style={{ position: 'relative' }}>`

Comment: I tried that and it pushes everything downward. But, again, I am importing App bar and placing it onto different components. But thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening because the MaterialUI App Bar defaults to `position="fixed"`. This separates it from the standard DOM's layout to allow content to scroll beneath it, but as a result no space is made for it on the page.

You can get around this by wrapping all content below it in a div and specifying enough margin, or by changing the `position` property of `<AppBar>` so it's no longer `"fixed"`. In your example, you could also just apply the styles to `<Box>` if that's the only content below the `<AppBar>`.

e.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Typography, Box } from '@material-ui/core';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar>
                <Typography variant='h3'>
                    AppBar
                </Typography>
            </AppBar>
            <div style={{marginTop: 80}}>
                <Box>
                    <Typography variant='h1' style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
                        Hello
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The code illustrated above is not what I was looking for, as any fixed size div will not work with a variable size app bar (as stated in the question).
However simply changing the AppBar position did the trick. So accepting this solution.

Answer (score 5):

MaterialUI provides a theme mixin for the AppBar that can help. Not sure if you're using the recomended JSS setup, but you can do something like this:

```
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
const styles = theme => ({
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar
});

const style = withStyles(styles)

function MyScreen ({ classes }) {
  <AppBar></AppBar>
    <div className={classes.appBarSpacer}></div>
  <Box></Box>
}

export default style(MyScreen)
```

The mixin will give that div the same height as your AppBar, pushing down the other content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't the appBarSpacer's height going to be fixed to 64px though? I tried this option, placing items in the AppBar which modify its height, and the appBarSpacer doesn't seem to adjust?

Comment: @Will59 I just tried this, and the height adjusts depending on the app bar's height.  The app bar height will responsively change heights depending on your window width & app bar props/config. **Edit:** I think I misunderstood your comment.  It sounds like your app bar height is custom, which this approach would not account for.

Answer (score 5):

According to Material-ui, there are 3 solutions to this problem.

https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#fixed-placement

> 1. You can use position="sticky" instead of fixed. ⚠️ sticky is not supported by IE 11.
> 2. You can render a second  component
> 3. You can use theme.mixins.toolbar CSS

I personally enjoy using the 2nd solution like this.

```
  return (
    <>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>{/* content */}</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Toolbar />
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

`<AppBar position='static'>`

use this it will do it and content won't hide under Appear

Answer (score 1):

I think having a good app setup is opinianted, but I would recommend the following

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  AppBar,
  Typography,
  Box,
  CssBaseline,
  makeStyles,
  Container,
  Grid,
  Toolbar
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: "100vh",
    overflow: "auto"
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4)
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="absolute">
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <Typography
            component="h1"
            variant="h6"
            color="inherit"
            noWrap
            className={classes.title}
          >
            AppBar
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
        <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Box>
                <Typography variant="h1" style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
                  Hello
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: How the result should look]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't the appBarSpacer's height going to be fixed to 64px though? I tried this option, placing items in the AppBar which modify its height, and the appBarSpacer doesn't seem to adjust?

Comment: Why would you modify the height of the appBar?

Comment: You'd modify the height if you wanted to add a logo (that can't be shrunk past a certain size) to the appbar, change the text size, or any number of other things...

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        marginBottom: 56,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        marginBottom: 64,
    },
},
menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
},
title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
}, }))
```

You can add the above to your code like this

```
const Navbar = () => {
const classes = useStyles()
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position='fixed' color='primary'>
            <Toolbar>
                <IconButton
                    edge='start'
                    className={classes.menuButton}
                    color='inherit'
                    aria-label='menu'>
                    <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.title}>
                    News
                </Typography>
                <Button color='inherit'>Login</Button>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    </div>
)}
```

For more documentation visit [material-ui breakpoint customization](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries)

Comment: Please avoid posting code as answer as this might not be helpful without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest trick can be giving position as sticky to Appbar. For reference, you can see the below attached image!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2lw3.png)

Comment: It would be best to paste in the code snippet directly rather than linking an image. Additionally, be sure to use helpful link text.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MUI ResponsiveAppBar component in my Vite-React app, and tried all it said here to change the bar's attributes, with no success, due to the fact that the bar is rendered on every page and doesn't "know" about the other components rendering on a specific page. My solution was to add a css class within index.css like this:

```
.content-container {
margin-top: 80px;
}
```

and then to add that class as an attribute in each page for the div rendering the rest of the components. For example in the homepage:

```
import React from "react";

function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div className="content-container">
            <h1>Home Page of App</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

This will create a margin (that you can specify) on the top part of the page so that the appbar doesn't "cover" other content on the page. It shouldn't affect the responsive nature of the app in any way from what I've checked.